# Does phonegap protect my urls?

Tags: jquery, security, phonegap-build

If I have a simple javascript string in my code:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/api/39899jkdfnkdfglhiygb3kkldflmgkd/getSecretInfo';
```

And I then use JSON to get the data. I then compile this using phonegap and make it available online. Can someone figure out this secret url in my code? How do I get around this?

Comment: You may need to rethink your architecture so that it doesn't depend on giving the user a secret and hoping they don't look at it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone figure out this secret url in my code?

Yes, your app is just a zip file.

> How do I get around this ?

Using obfuscation, but somebody might be able to retrieve your secret.
[How can I obfuscate (protect) JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscateprotect-javascript)